# Is it possible to use custom connector with IoT Edge Runtime

Tags: iot, azure-iot-edge

Today I have a bit tricky question. Imagine a situation when someone has written a custom connector to the network (let's say there are a lot of security features hidden and so on). Now imagine that each application can connect to the network (even IoT Edge Runtime) only through this custom connector (let's say, this connector has implementation of both https and plain MQTT protocols).

Now the issue! According to the documentation here https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/networking.md the IoT Edge Runtime connects to the network through moby-engine modified by Microsoft. According to the Microsoft, we cannot get this moby-engine. Moreover, if we use original moby project the support from the Microsoft will be caught off, which is a bad thing. So, we cannot modify moby-engine and make it use this custom connector.

Now the question!
Is it possible (may be I missed something in documentation. Not the first time tbh) to use custom connector with IoT Edge Runtime (no proxy, we need plain MQTT protocol)? If yes, can you explain in details how? If no, what posible features inside Iot Edge Runtime/moby engine can help to use custom connector?

Please ask, if you need more information. I will provide it right away. A similar question was asked by me on Microsoft github. No response from there.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but it sounds like want to build a protocol gateway. This is one of the key scenarios IoT Edge was built for. See an example in the official modbus connector https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/deploy-modbus-gateway

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me check it! But I think, it can work!

Comment: I found another possible solution to the problem described above. In my case this https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/devdoc/porting_guide.md looks more promising. Thank you for giving hints to move to the right direction!

Comment: @user1415536 can you add your solution as the answer to this question?

Comment: @asergaz I posted all three possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposal from @silent pointed me to the correct direction. While reading manuals, how to properly setup a gateway, I once again began to read manual about creating custom modules. This pointed me to have a look at preparing a build environment. This again directed me to the SDK bit.

Honestly speaking, by accident and mostly out of curiosity I clicked the link about porting the SDK to my custom platform. This was the solution in my case https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/devdoc/porting_guide.md

I have to mention here two other solutions I walked through:

1. Proxy server that supports your custom connector/protocol (will
   work for cases where you do not need MQTT. However, MQTT websockets
   can be used here)
2. Gateway. This is definitely a good one. Again many thanks to @silent.

Which one will work in your particular case is only up to you to decide.